# why does sorting a table in Lua doesn't work

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have a piece of Lua code that generate an error and I don't understand how to solve it.

```
  .............................
 local last_num = 0 
 local  channelTable={} 
 for num in channels.each_number() do  --  channels.each_number() returns 1.number  in each call 
  channelTable[last_num] =num;
  last_num = last_num +1;
 end    
 table.sort(channelTable);
```

based on lua documentation I can use the function `sort` to sort the saved numbers in `channelTable`. the error that I get is:

```
attempt to index global 'table'
```

Any idea how can I solve this, or should implement bubble sort?
thanks for any hint!

Comment: Can you run a simple script separately that prints out the `_G` table? That'll at least tell us if `table` and other standard lua facilities are available in your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you haven't loaded the table library or you have overwritten it by accident.

The error message seems truncated: it should say why indexing failed.

Comment: that the error message that I get, I'm using Lua on a HTML page run on ARM9. and that all I get the rest of the error message is only about the path of the lua file, how can load the table  ?
by the way thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Engine, there should be `(a xxx value)` at the end of the message.

Comment: thant a lot for you help but No :  I'm using   haserl CGI  !

Comment: thanks again for your the lib was explecitly rejected, I didn't know since I didn't stared the project !

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing indicates that the table library is not available. It's unlikely that this core library isn't part of your Lua environment, so it's likely you have assigned something to table elsewhere in your code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there away to load it explicitly using the require statement

Comment: As I understand it, the base libraries are built into the Lua interpreter at compile time, and can't be loaded as modules, as there is no library to look in to find them. I could be completely wrong though - I've never used a Lua environment where the table library wasn't available. What do you get if you try: print(table); to see what the name refers to?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that you are expecting channels.each_number() to be called in each iteration of the loop.  If I'm not mistaken, I think it only gets called the first time the program goes through the loop.  Whatever you use in the`for..in` loop needs to be a table, I believe. So I guess the problem is that your table isn't being generated as you want it to.  Try doing this:

```
print('number of items in channelTable = ' .. #channelTable)
```

If it comes out to 0, then what I said is probably the problem.

Comment: No defintly not the code works exactly the way I want when out comment the table line